# Tableau extract using row store vs Column store DBs

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a .TDE(tableau extract) from a table in sql server which has around 180+ columns and 60 million records and is taking around 4 hours in current infra of 16GB RAM and 12 cores

I was looking for any other way by which this can be done faster. I would like to know if I could load my data into any column store DB which can connect to tableau and then create a TDE from the data in the column store DB can make a bit better in performance.

If yes, please suggest any such column store DB

Comment: In Desktop, turn on Performance Recording and then generate the extract. When it's done generating, turn off Performance Recording. Tableau will then open a new workbook with visualizations of how long each part of the TDE build process takes. For example, it breaks out the database sql call, the tableau data engine call, and a few other things. At the very least, this will tell you if it's Tableau slowing you down or your database.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tableau SDK](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk.htm) is a way to build TDE files without having to use Desktop. You can try it and see if you get better performance.

Does your TDE need all 180+ columns? You can get a noticeable performance improvement if your TDE contains only the columns you need.

Comment: Hi Sam, I have already used tableau SDK on spark standalone but I am not getting noticeable performance. Yes, my TDE need all 180 columns. I read that less columns has good performance here in this link.https://community.tableau.com/thread/119052

Comment: What version of Tableau are you using? The most recent versions (10.5 beta, maybe 10.4?) claim a massive performance improvement for their data engine, now called Hyper.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore, Hyper is in 10.5 beta.